VS code setup failure in bazel
the final step to set up internal market place fails
Failed Installing Extensions: file:///tmp/vscode-internal-marketplace.vsix, file:///tmp/getting-started-with-bazel.vsix, file:///tmp/sfdc-vscode-coreapp.vsix
a [Error]: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/vscode-internal-marketplace.vsix'
    at v (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:18:13405)
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:18:14842
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/yauzl/index.js:37:21
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:23) {
  type: undefined,
  cause: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/vscode-internal-marketplace.vsix'] {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'open',
    path: '/tmp/vscode-internal-marketplace.vsix'
  }
}
a [Error]: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/sfdc-vscode-coreapp.vsix'
    at v (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:18:13405)
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:18:14842
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/yauzl/index.js:37:21
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:23) {
  type: undefined,
  cause: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/sfdc-vscode-coreapp.vsix'] {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'open',
    path: '/tmp/sfdc-vscode-coreapp.vsix'
  }
}
a [Error]: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/getting-started-with-bazel.vsix'
    at v (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:18:13405)
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:18:14842
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/yauzl/index.js:37:21
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:23) {
  type: undefined,
  cause: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/getting-started-with-bazel.vsix'] {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'open',
    path: '/tmp/getting-started-with-bazel.vsix'
  }

